# Correct way to write unit tests for instance method with pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I want to write unittests for class with several methods for data transformation.

High level:

```
class my_class:

    def __init__(self, file):
        # read data out of .yml config file
        config = read_data_from_yml_config(file)
        self.value1 = config["value1"]
        self.value2 = config["value2"]

    def get_and_transform(self):
        data_dict = self.get_data()
        transformed_data = self.transform_data(data_dict)

        return transformed_data

    def get_data(self):
        data_dict = request_based_on_value1(self.value1)
        return data_dict

    def transform_data(self, data_dict):
        trnsf = transform1(data_dict, self.value2)

        return trnsf
```

Here, I have several questions. The main thing to test here ist `my_class.transform_data()`. 
It takes a dict as an input, reads it as a pandas data frame and does some transformations.

In my understanding, I need several fixtures `d1`, `d2`, `d3`, ... (as different values for `data_dict`) which represent the different test case inputs for my_class.transform_data(). As I want to make sure that the output is as expected, I would als define my expected output:

```
o1 # expected output for transform_data(d1)
o2, o3, ... # respectively
```

Several questions to that:

1. Is this approach correct?
2. How and where would I specify `d1`, `d2`, ... and `o1`, `o2`,....? I could either do that in the `test_my_class.py`-file or store d1_sample.pkl, ... in the `tests/` folder.
   Here I would chose a minimal example for both `d` and `o`
3. As the transformation in `transform_data` also depends on the attribute `self.value2`, how would I pass in different values for `value2` without creating an instance
   of `my_class`?

In general, it is also not fully clear to me whether I would test on an "object"-level or on a "method" level. Above, I described a "method"-approach 
(because I am mainly interested in the results of `transform_data`). The alternative would be to provide different .yml files and thus creating 
different test instances of `my_class`.

```
def yml1():
    config = read_in_yml1()
    return config

# and so on for different configurations.
```

then for the test:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input, expected", [(yml1, ???), (yml2, ???)])
def test_my_class():
    test_class = my_class(file)

    assert test_class.transform_data == expected
```

However, as the function input to `my_class.transform_data()` does not depend (directly) from the content of `yml1`, but rather the response of `my_class.get_data()`, that seems to make little sense. How would I test for different input values of `data_dict`?

What is the correct way to write unit tests in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert at all but I find your problem interesting, so I'm gonna try to post an answer that is careful and constructive at the same time:

1. Your approach of verifying that `transform_data` behaves as expected with regards to pairs of inputs and outputs seems valid to me. Unit tests verify that the smallest components ("units") in your source code behave as expected, and I would say that the behavior of your three methods is different enough to make these methods units.
2. If you are not sure on whether to declare pairs of input dictionaries and expected outputs inside your test file or in external .pkl files, I guess that these input/output pairs are either large (in size) or many (in number):

   - In the first case, you could declare a default `data_dict` input dictionary and a default expected output as two fixtures that you can later [monkeypatch](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html) inside a test function. You can parametrize the test function with different values that correspond to elements in the `data_dict` dictionary, and then [monkeypatch the elements of the default `data_dict` fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html#monkeypatching-dictionaries) with these parametrized values.
   - In the second case, I think it would be advisable to reduce the number of test cases to a few relevant ones, and try to keep their input/output specification inside the test file.
3. You could pass in different values for `value2` by (again) monkeypatching the `value2` property of an instance of `my_class`. You would however need to declare such an instance at least once (either inside or outside your function).

Like I was writing above, testing on a "method-level" rather than an "object-level" seems valid to me also for object-oriented software. Providing different .yml files and creating different instances of your class (so testing on an "object-level" like you said) looks to me like a first step into doing *integration* tests. I might be wrong on this last point, but hopefully someone can improve my answer on this or other points :)